# Mailchimp HTML Signup Form not working. JQuery problem?

Tags: html, jquery, mailchimp

Hi I am attempting to embed a Mailchimp signup form into my app built on GoodBarber. It works on Android, but when I submit my info on iOS I get redirected to an empty unstyled form that appears to be hosted through Mailchimp. I see on this support page that it may be due to a JQuery conflict, but I’m not sure how to fix it. Is there something I can add or change to this code that will make my signup form work properly on iOS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <style>
    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }
    
        #mailchimp h2 {
            color: white;
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            font-size: 30px;
            }
            #mailchimp .mc-field-group {
                color: white;
                font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 300;
    
            }
            #mce-EMAIL, #mce-FNAME, #mce-LNAME, #mce-PHONE {
                display: block;
                margin-top: 6px;
            }
        #mailchimp {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            color: #3D6392;
            padding: 20px 15px;
        }
            #mailchimp input {
                border: medium none;
            color: gray;
                font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            padding: 8px 10px;
            width: 300px;
                border-radius: 20px;
                -moz-border-radius: 20px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
            }
                #mailchimp input.email { background: #fff }
                #mailchimp input.name { background: #fff}
                #mailchimp input\[type="submit"\] {
                    background: #492D7E;
                    color: #fff;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    font-size: 15px;
                    width: 75%;
                    padding: 8px 0;
                    margin-bottom: 15px;
                    margin-top: 20px;
                }
    
                #mailchimp input\[type="submit"\]:hover { color: #F2C94C }
    
        </style>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="mailchimp">
            <form action="https://bioharmonictechnologies.us19.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=f5364fb7b05f96eb21a4e656b&amp;id=9d068ce5e2" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                <h2>Join Our Community!</h2>
            <!-- <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div> -->
            <div class="mc-field-group">
                <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email
            </label>
                <input type="email" size="20" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group">
                <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name
            </label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group">
                <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name
            </label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="required" id="mce-LNAME">
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
                <label for="mce-PHONE">Phone Number
            </label>
                <input type="text" name="PHONE" class="required" value="" id="mce-PHONE">
            </div>
                <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_f5364fb7b05f96eb21a4e656b_9d068ce5e2" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe to Newsletter" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You may want to remove the `[` at the beginning and `][1]` at the end of your code

Comment: Is there any way you can add get the error?

Comment: I'm not seeing the [ @Dominik

Comment: All cleaned up now